# Run-time 52 Bad file name or number error on one network system

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am receiving the Run-time error '52' bad file name or number error, however all of the questions which cover this on stackoverflow that I can see have answers which involve changing the code. The problem with this is that the code uses a directory in a network drive, and the error doesn't occur on other computers on the network.

It is perhaps worth noting that my computer until recently did not have an activated version of windows due to a complication, however I assumed that to be the cause of the error but it is still occurring after activation.

I have no experience with Microsoft Visual Basic and did not write the code so if you need any more information just ask.

```
Private Sub Command1769_Click()
Me.Refresh

If Len(Dir("file location" & 
[Combo1199], vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
MkDir "file location" & 
[Combo1199]
End If
```

I have replaced the name of the file location with 'file location' however I have checked and it is correct. The [Combo1199] is the name of a folder which is already present in the directory, and its date modified shows as being when the VBA code was run. The debug shows the problem as occurring on the If Len(... line

EDIT SOLVED: For some reason the DNS servers weren't set to be found automatically so I wasn't connected to the applicable license server.

Comment: The `If Len(...` line is doing too many things for this to be easily debuggable. Pull the `String` expression building the file name / path into its own local variable, then place a breakpoint (F9) on the `If Len(Dir(thatVariable, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then` line and validate the contents of that variable when the breakpoint is hit. Is the path on a network drive or a UNC path? Or is it local? I understand you might not want to show us the full path, but the type of path is relevant to the question.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I created a string where NewString = "file location" & [Combo1199] and then checked it in the VBA IDE, but the same error occurred. I believe it's a UNC path; the file location is in the form ````"\\networkdrive\directory\...\directory\"````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amongst other possible reasons, in my experience, run-time error 52 can arise when a path is valid but inaccessible, for example, a mapped network drive for which the user has insufficient read permissions, or which cannot be accessed due to the target being offline.

I would therefore suggest that you print the path represented by `"file location" & [Combo1199]` to the Immediate Window (view this using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in the VBA IDE) using:

```
Debug.Print "file location" & [Combo1199]
```

And then ensure that you can access this location 'manually' through File Explorer from the same PC, using the same user credentials that are active when the code runs.

Comment: I do have access to the file, however the network drive has a different name. I know that the other computers on the network use the same network drive name as I do, so I don't know why it would only give an error on my computer. Also, I had been using VBA successfully up until getting this error and I don't see what would have changed.

Comment: I also ran ````C:\> net use```` in command prompt on my computer and another on the same network on which the VBA runs correctly and they show the same mapped network drives

Comment: Update: I pinged the network drive from the vba code, and it could not find the host. I did the same thing from a computer which was working, and unsurprisingly it worked fine, so I used the ip address and was able to ping that, so now just need to connect to the server

Comment: @JonathanDyke Glad you were able to solve the problem!